# Can't Get Data from snapshot from firebase. object is always null

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am new to firebase database I don't know why I can't get data into my object from the database

when I am calling data from firebase database this will give right data but I can't set it to my object or text view any help, please 
check the screenshot of firebase database that is my database screen so how can I get data from that type of JSON

```
public class ProfileFrag extends Fragment {
TextView name,companyName,emailAddress, mobileNumber,companyAddress;
  FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference myRef;
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // init
        name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        companyName = view.findViewById(R.id.company_name);
        emailAddress = view.findViewById(R.id.gmail_address);
        mobileNumber = view.findViewById(R.id.mobile_number);
        companyAddress = view.findViewById(R.id.address);


        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String key = sharedPreferences.getString("Key","");

        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(key).child("PersonalData");

        myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
         BossModel data =  dataSnapshot.child("PersonalData").getValue(BossModel.class);
                companyAddress.setText(data.getCompanyAddress());
                name.setText(data.getName());
                companyName.setText(data.getCompanyName());
                emailAddress.setText(data.getEmailAddress());
                mobileNumber.setText(data.getMobileNumber());  }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

in sign in I did like this

```
Map<String,Object> boss = new HashMap<>();
                    boss.put("Name",sFullName.getText().toString().trim());
                    boss.put("Company Name",sCompanyName.getText().toString().trim());
                    boss.put("Email Address",sEmailAddress.getText().toString().trim());
                    boss.put("Mobile Number",sMobileNumber.getText().toString().trim());
                    boss.put("Company Address",sCompanyAddress.getText().toString().trim());
                    String key = userRef.push().getKey();
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("Key",key);
                    editor.apply();
                    userRef.child(key).child("PersonalData").setValue(boss);
                    signIn();
```

I am Attaching screenshot of firebase database also  [firebase database screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7blAW.png)

[here is error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKQVB.png)

Comment: what error are you getting ? whats on the logcat? You are getting `Key` from sharedpref, where are you storing it in sharedpref?

Comment: I am storing the key in sharedpref  when user create an account  and I am also going to add error screen for your reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching data from wrong node.

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(key).child("PersonalData");
```

You are already on

```
key->PersonalData
```

**Notice:** Are you sure your database don't have any Parent node? Can you show me full database structure? If you're sure, change like below.

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(key).child("PersonalData");

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
//Here I made change
     BossModel data =  dataSnapshot.getValue(BossModel.class);
            companyAddress.setText(data.getCompanyAddress());
            name.setText(data.getName());
            companyName.setText(data.getCompanyName());

 emailAddress.setText(data.getEmailAddress());


   mobileNumber.setText(data.getMobileNumber());  }
//The rest are the same.
```

**Note** If this doesn't solve, I need to see your full Database structure.

Comment: i did that but still not solved but i think i made mistake in adding data so i had added that code can you check that please

Comment: Is Your **userRef** on **FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();** ?I mean ,there is no parent reference??  If so, did you change **ChildEventListener** to **ValueEventListener**??